# Unexpected redirect after logout

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I've made a login form using angular and Ionic, [Here](https://inventar.torhelge.no/home) you can log in with any uid or pin that's between 4 and 6 digits. The problem I have is that when you've logged in, and used my logout function, if you're not on the home page, you get redirected to the page you were on after you log out. So if you're on your profile page, and click logout, you get redirected to the home page, then you are sent back, and I have no idea why is this happening.

The system is temporary for now, you don't get authenticated by the server, I just have a session variable named "logedin".

My logout function:

```js
logut() {
  sessionStorage.clear();
  location.reload();
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

The source [code](https://github.com/nitram9876/Inventar/tree/master).

Comment: Why are you doing this `location.reload()`? That should not be there, just use the angular router to route where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have `location.reload()`. That doesn't belong into SPA.

```js
logout() {
  sessionStorage.clear();
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Comment: Hi, its there so that i get logged out even when im on the home page, when it wasnt there i would get logged out in the backend but the stuff displayed on the page wouldnt change before i reloaded the page, reloading it programatically was just a quick fix, a better way to solve it would be much apreciated